# NSNumber * to NSString * from CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsstring, nsnumber

I currently have an `NSArray` of objects that have come from CoreData - one of the properties (named `identifier`) is an `NSNumber`. I'm doing some comparisons in my code and need to convert this `NSNumber` to a `NSString`.

I've got this to work, however I am wondering what the difference between these two pieces of code is:

```
NSNumber * arrayValueNum = [coreArray[i] identifier];
NSString * arrayValue = [arrayValueNum stringValue];
```

and

```
NSString * test = [[coreArray[i] identifier] stringValue];
```

For some reason this second snippet will not compile, and the first one will.

**Error:**

> no visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'stringValue'

Aren't they the same, except that the `NSNumber *` value is in the braces instead of being in it's own variable?

Comment: Quick question: To what method goes `identifier` on the second snippet (if you alt+click on it)? I guess, that `[[(MyCoreDataClass*)coreArray[i] identifier] stringValue]` might work, or `[(NSNumber *)[coreArray[i] identifier] stringValue]` too. The thing, is that `coreArray[i]` returns an `id` object, and there are some object that have a property/method `identifier` that returns a `NSString` which would explain the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stringWithFormat` to directly assign value to that `NSString` variable like this.

```
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[coreArray[i] identifier]];
```

Comment: This results in an error when using `[test isEqualToString]` -  `[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`